# Self nested infinite routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to self nest a resource in the routes infinetelly?

Suppose the following scenario: I want to create several pages that may be self nested one to another, like a products page has many product pages and each product page has several sub-pages etc. 
The resource would be a page in a tree structure , like with the [`awesome nested set gem`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set).

In case an admin can create pages at unknown depth level how  would I make the routes?

The above example has to produce a url like `/:friendly_id_of_level_1/:friendly_id_of_level_2/.../:friendly_id_of_level_n`

I've tried going with dynamic routes but it has many drawbacks this way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do a similar thing to this in one of my apps with this route:

```
map.connect "/c/*modules", :controller => "content", :action => "show"
```

(Note this is using rails2 routing syntax, you might need to update it).

This will resolve this url

```
/c/123-foo/456-bar/789-baz/653-qux
```

to the `content#show` action, with params set like

```
params = {"modules"=>[123-foo", "456-bar", "789-baz", "653-qux"]}
```

The modules are in a tree structure, so i can use the sequence of module ids in params[:modules] to make a breadcrumb chain and any other heirarchical data, and i use the last one in the array as the "current" one to actually show to the user.

Note:  I put the "/c/" at the start of the url to separate these nested routes out from all my other routes:  otherwise it's very greedy and will match pretty much any url on your site.  That's not a problem if you want to always have it as your "catchall" route down at the bottom of your routes file, but if not then you'll need to add something to make it distinct.  Obviously this doesn't need to be "/c/", you could have anything which will stop it colliding with your other routes.

Comment: hi and thank you for your answer.
What do you do in case of same module names, in different paths? 
How do you handle direct urls at c/653-qux when they should be
 /c/123-foo/456-bar/789-baz/653-qux  or /c/123-foo/653-qux
Don't you have conflicts with 'em?

Comment: There's no conflict as such: `/c/653-qux` and `/c/123-foo/456-bar/789-baz/653-qux` will both show the content page for the module with id 653.  (`653-qux` is generated from the to_param method).  However, if you call the longer url you'll also get some extra info about the path you took down to that module, which can be used to generate the breadcrumbs.

Comment: BTW my module structure isn't a strict one-to-many tree:  it's more like many-to-many, ie the same child could be on several different parent branches.  If you did have a strict tree structure where each child is on a single branch then you could generate the breadcrumbs by looking up the ancestors of `653-qux`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Although I was thinking of one to many relations, the many to many approach you have  is also tricky.
It restricts the resources to have uniqueness on the attribute that generates the url.
But what in the case an admin goes and creates a page like products/info and another one like company/info ? How will the server respond to /info request?

I was inspired by your approach nevertheless and I am trying something similar , though I must say I am a little worried for cases like the above.

Comment: Yep, many to many does require you to use unique identifiers.  If it was one to many then as you say the only requirement is that ideintifiers are unique within their siblings.  However, that assumes that further down the line someone won't want to use the exact same article (or whatever) in two seperate places.  There might be another way that lets you mix and match.  If you can get away with having totally unique identifiers (slugs or ids) within the url then i would strongly recommend it as it makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: Btw, on the site i was talking about (which has a huge amount of content) the urls might look like this `/c/135921-scheme/135922-year-1/135930-autumn-2/135934-step-4`.  Obviously they are quite "numbery".  Ultimately you have to decide if you really **need** nice urls.  Often people start out with nice readable urls, then after the site has been going a while and gets bigger it becomes impossible to ensure nice readable urls, and they give up and stick loads of ids in there.  Most people don't care what's in the address bar as long as it works (and iOS safari just shows the domain anyway).